# SQL Recursive Join

Tags: sql, join, recursion, self-join

I have a Table called "Level" which has a column, "idParent" that makes a self reference.

What I want to do is to retrieve a tuple with the entire hierarchy..
Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Recursive and hierarchical queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL)  are not standard. Some databases support them, some don't, and the support varies.

See the link above for a backgrounder.

Comment: I got @zbmq, thanks for your support.
That wasn't what I was looking for, but may help at some point.

Comment: You can probably try and pivot the result of a recursive query and get what you wanted.